# Fondo de texto mas ancho que imagen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de crear una plantilla como la primera imagen.
 Pero parte de donde se encuentra el texto es más ancho que la imagen, y además las imagenes de lado derecho tendria que repartirlos dependiendo del alto de la imagen izquierda.

el código que estoy manejando hasta el momento.

CSS

```
figure img{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid red;               
}

.content{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width:100%;
    min-height:120px;               
    padding:0px 0px 20px 20px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row ">      
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <figure class="">
            <img src="img/nosotros/1.jpg" alt="Valor 1" class="img-responsive ">
        </figure>
        <figcaption class="content">
            <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <figure class="">
            <img src="img/nosotros/2.jpg" alt="Valor 2" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </figure>
        <figcaption class="content">
            <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <figure class="">
            <img src="img/nosotros/2.jpg" alt="Valor 3" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </figure>
        <figcaption class="content">
            <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
        </figcaption>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguna sugerencia para arreglar mi detalle?
uso botstrap 3.3.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He trabajado tu código y le he encontrado varios detalles.

En primera, figcaption no puede tener div parent, jamás lo he usado, así que busqué la documentación y ahí aparece que la forma de hacerlo debe ser como la siguiente:

```
<figure>
    <img src="/media/examples/elephant-660-480.jpg"
         alt="Elephant at sunset">
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
```

En otras noticias, hay muchas formas de solucionar esta situación, te comparto dos ejemplos en el enlace para que te inspires.

[Demo: Inspiring cards - bootstrap 3 by Mariyselita](https://codepen.io/Mariyselita/pen/xxbrNgQ?editors=1100)

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Te animo a que agregues el código que has compartido en el enlace dentro de tu respuesta haciendo clic en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/318513/edit), recuerda que el link podría dejar de funcionar en el futuro

Answer (score 1):

El problema que había en tu código eran algunas posiciones absolutas y un `padding` que te estaba empujando los elementos de manera no deseada. He hecho algunos ajustes en tu código que espero que te sean útiles. Básicamente si tienes controlados los tamaños de las imágenes de fondo debería funcionarte sin problema, yo he puesto un color de `background` para que se vea lo que he cambiado. Otra manera para pasarle las imágenes y controlar sus dimensiones es precisamente pasárselas como `background-image:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat`; puedes probar con eso también.

```css
   figure img{
                        margin-bottom:20px;
                        border:1px solid red;               
                    }

                    .content{
                        position: relative; 
                        bottom: 0;
                        background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
                        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
                        color: #f1f1f1;
                        width: auto;
                        min-height:120px;               
                        /*padding:0px 0px 20px 20px; */
                    }     

                    .contendorGrande{min-width: 100%;background-color: red;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <body class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <figure class="">
                  <img src="img/nosotros/1.jpg" alt="Valor 1" class="img-responsive ">
              </figure>
              <figcaption class="content">
                  <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                  <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
              </figcaption>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <figure class="">
                  <img src="img/nosotros/2.jpg" alt="Valor 2" class="img-responsive center-block">
              </figure>
              <figcaption class="content">
                  <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                  <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</p>
              </figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <figure class="">
                  <img src="img/nosotros/2.jpg" alt="Valor 3" class="img-responsive center-block">
              </figure>
              <figcaption class="content">
                  <h2 class="val">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                  <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
              </figcaption>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
        </body>
```